# Search for a key in lua which contains a certain string

Tags: python, lua, lua-table

I have multiple lua files which contain information I would like to extract via Python. To use Lua inside Python I'm using [lunatic-python](https://github.com/bastibe/lunatic-python), but thats not a requirement - if you have other approaches that would also be fine.

The lua files look like that:

```
source = {
    licences = {
        "GPL",
        "MIT",
    },
    env = {
        MYTOOL_VERSION = "1.2.3",
        OTHER_KEY = "OTHER_VALUE",
    },
    some_other_keys = {
        ...
    },
}
```

The value I'm interested in is `source.env.MYTOOL_VERSION`, while `MYTOOL`is always something different. Since I have no experience in lua, I have no Idea how to tell it to "get the value of the key which contains the string `VERSION`". I read some tutorials about the `tables` concept in Lua (which still seems a bit weird to me), and I guess the functions `next` or `pairs` could be usefull for my case. Though those functions still confuse me, in the examples I found they are always used in loop, but when I do something like this:

```
x = next(source.env)
```

instead of

```
k, v = next(source.env)
```

it seems that `x` now only contains the key, not the value. And when using `pairs` instead of `next`, I get a function, but I have no idea how to call it.

My Pythonscript currently looks like this:

```
import lua

with open(project_path) as f:
    script = f.read()

lua.execute(script)

i = 1

licences = []

while True:
    data = lua.globals().source.licences[i]
    if data is None:
        break
    licences.append(data)
    i += 1

version = lua.eval('source.env[next(source.env)]') if lua.globals().source.env is not None else 'unkown',
```

Which just gets the value of *any* key in the `env` table, not necessarily the one which contains `VERSION`.

So, what is an elegant solution to fetch the desired data of this file to use it with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute this script

```
function version(t)
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if k:match"._VERSION$" then return v end
    end
end
```

And then eval `version(source.env)`, I would expect it to return the 1.2.3 for you